# How to install PostgreSQL 14 on manjaro linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, manjaro

I need to install postgresql version 14 on manjaro Linux, but actual version is 15. How do I do it?

I tried to install postgresql 14 version in manjaro linux

Answer (score 0):

You can use code below.You'll see available packages and their versions for Postgresql. For more information [here.](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Pacman_Overview#Searching_for_Packages)

```
pacman -Ss postgresql
```

I found `extra/postgresql-old-upgrade 14.6-1` when i searched for available packages.
You can run code below and install old version for postgresql.

```
pamac install postgresql-old-upgrade
```

Comment: postgresql-old-upgrade 14.6-1 is a build for migrating between major versions 14 and 15 with pg_upgrade, it is not postgresql 14

Comment: As far as I know, you should downgrade after installing the latest version of postgresql in manjaro.